# The adjoint operators as elliptic operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, differential-operators, elliptic-operators

Assume  that  $M$ is  a smooth  $n$  dimensional manifold  with  $n>1$.

Is there a  lie  algebra  structure  on $\chi^{\infty} (M)$, the  space  of  all  smooth  vector  fields  on $M$,  such that   we  have the   following  property:

> For  every  vector  field  $X\in \chi^{\infty}(M)$ the   operator $ad_X:\chi^{\infty}(M) \to \chi^{\infty}(M)$  with $ad_{X}(Y)=[X,Y]$ is  an  elliptic  differential operator of  positive (non zero) order acting on the  space  of  smooth  vector  fields  on $M\setminus S$ where  $S$  is  the set  of singular points  of  $X$.

Here  is  the  MO  link of this  question

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271336/the-adjoint-operators-as-elliptic-operators

## EDIT:

According to answers to MO  link, can one  imagine a  Lie structure  on $\chi^{\infty}(M)$ whose adjoint operator would  be a  differential operator of  order $d>1$?